# using variable inside set command -- Linux shell script

Tags: shell, expect

I want to use variables inside set command. Is it possible to use ? when i use it is unable to recognize

```
 set MYVAR [lindex $argv 0]
 set servername [lindex $argv 1]
 set osusername [lindex $argv 2]
 spawn ssh "osusername@$servername"
 expect "password:"
 send "$MYVAR\r"
 send "/hyp_util/PasswordChanges/automation/deleteexistingentry.sh\r"
 set cmd [format {cat "/home/currentosusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" | ssh "$osusername@$servername" 'cat >> /home/$servername/.ssh/authorized_keys'}]
 spawn sh -c "$cmd"
 expect "password:"
 send "$MYVAR\r"
 send "exit\r"
 interact
```

No error but it is not recognizing the `servname` and `osusername` variables in set command

```
set cmd [format {cat "/home/currentosusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" | ssh "$osusername@$servername" 'cat >> /home/$servername/.ssh/authorized_keys'}]
```

Comment: This appears to be tcl, so I added that tag.  There's almost no hope of an answer to a language-dependent question without a language tag.  If I've guessed wrong, please change the tag to the scripting language you're actually using.

Comment: *Which command* is unable to recognize *what*? Please be more specific and show any error messages you are getting.

Comment: sorry added now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have these definitions:

```
set servname [lindex $argv 1]
set osusername [lindex $argv 2]
```

and these substitutions:

```
set cmd [format {cat "/home/currentosusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" | ssh "$osuername@$servername" 'cat >> /home/$servername/.ssh/authorized_keys'}]
```

here, you are trying to substitute `osuername` instead of `osusername`, and `servername` instead of `servname`. The names need to correspond.

Also, the braces (`{ }`) prevent variable substitution. You can get around that by using the `format` command to insert values:

```
set cmd [format {cat "/home/currentosusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" | ssh "%1$s@%2$s" 'cat >> /home/%2$s/.ssh/authorized_keys'} $osusername $servname]
```

Documentation:
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm)

Comment: sorry for typo mistakes... i will try this..thank you

Comment: can we assign commands to set command like set serverusername `whoami`

Comment: It can be done, but it's not very good form. The trick is to set a read trace on the variable name and call `whoami` from the trace handler. Ask another question about that. I don't have Linux, but hopefully someone else will explain.